# Next.js conditional page rendering

Tags: javascript, next.js, server-side-rendering

Is is possible with next.js to server side render different pages or components based on certain conditions.

E.g. I would like to create a page that shows a complete different component for every day of the year. So on server side i would like to get the current date and based on this one render a certain component on the client side.

For testing i created following code:

```
export default function Home({seconds}: { seconds: number}) {
  if (seconds >= 30) {
    return (
      <h1 className="text-3xl font-bold underline">
        Hello Silvia
      </h1>
    )    
  } else {
    return (
      <h1 className="text-3xl font-bold underline">
        Hello Thomas!
      </h1>
    )
  }
}

export async function getServerSideProps(context: any) {
  const now = new Date()
  
  return {
    props: {
      seconds: now.getSeconds()
    },
  }
}
```

In general this is working but the if statement inside of the Home component is executed on the client side. So a user could easily manipulate the seconds variable. Is there a way to archive this on server side ?

Comment: the javascript logic inside getServerSideProps() is executed on server side, and nextjs only return a html page from request (including the conditional rendering), what do you mean by the client side execution?

Comment: Exactly so the seconds property is generated on the server side. But the actual if statement is executed on the client, or am i wrong ? So a user could easily set a breakpoint on the if statement and change the property and would see the content they should not see.  Is there any way to have this if statement on server side and return only the actual html either "hello silvia" or "hello thomas" ?

Comment: No, I think you got the wrong idea. the if else will not be executed on the client side, nextjs return HTML with either "hello silvia" or "hello thomas". You can check the HTML from Dev Console > Network > Doc, and for the execution you can test it by using `console.log` if you insert `console.log` inside `getServerSideProps()` the output will only available on your terminal, and if you do `console.log` inside the component, it will output on DevConsole > Console, and your terminal.